# ESP32 SSL connection works when CA Certificate is a constant, but not when read from a file

Tags: ssl, arduino, certificate, esp32

I have the following Arduino code I'm using with an ESP32:

```
  if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("Error mounting SPIFFS.");
  }

  File file = SPIFFS.open("/root.cer");

  if(!file) {
    Serial.println("Error opening the file.");
  }


  Serial.println("CA Root certificate: ");

  String ca_cert = file.readString();

  Serial.println(ca_cert);
  espClient.setCACert(ca_cert.c_str());

  file.close();
```

This is the relevant code for loading a file and setting the WiFiClientSecure's CA certificate. This code does not work.

However, if I replace `espClient.setCACert(ca_cert.c_str());` with `espClient.setCACert(ROOTCERT);` where `ROOTCERT` is defined as such:

```
#define ROOTCERT "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/\n" \
"MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT\n" \
"DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTIxMDkzMDE0MDExNVow\n" \
"PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD\n" \
"Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB\n" \
"AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O\n" \
"rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq\n" \
"OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b\n" \
"xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw\n" \
"7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD\n" \
"aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV\n" \
"HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG\n" \
"SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69\n" \
"ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr\n" \
"AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz\n" \
"R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5\n" \
"JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo\n" \
"Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

The code works.

The ROOTCERT string is taken directly from the certificate file, so they must be identical.

The certificate file was downloaded and exported using Windows's certificate exporter. I've tried converting line endings to no avail.

EDIT: I've found a clue.

If I do the following:

```
String constString = ROOTCERT;
espClient.setCACert(constString.c_str());
```

It also does not work.

<strike>And I added this code:</strike>

```
 if(strcmp(constString.c_str(), ROOTCERT))
     Serial.println("Constant and converted string are equal.");
   else
     Serial.println("Constant and converted string are different.");
```

And it prints "Constant and converted string are different."

So it appears to be some kind of problem with how `.c_str()` does things? I have no idea what this could be, though. When printed to the console, the `.c_str()`, ROOTCERT and ca_cert `String`s all appear IDENTICAL.

I am completely confused here.

Turns out I was using `strcmp()` incorrectly. Things are still not working.

Comment: Have you verified they're identical? Have you tried having your code compare the cert you read with the one that works?

Comment: I have. They are identical. However, I've added an edit that seems to be a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Your conditional with `strcmp()` is wrong. `strcmp()` returns 0 (false) if the strings are equal - you have it backwards.

Comment: Regardless, it's still broken.

Comment: If before you call `espClient.setCACert()` you add code that looks like `if(strcmp(ROOTCERT, ca_cert.c_str())) Serial.println("certificates differ"); else Serial.println("certificates identical");` what output do you see?

Comment: I assume I need to compare the result of strcmp() to 0 like you said before, and I get "certificates identical".

Comment: The code I wrote takes into account `strcmp()` returning 0 for equality. If you add `== 0` to it you'll invert its meaning. I need to know exactly what you added in order to be clear on what the results mean. Could you paste the lines you added in a comment?

Comment: I added `if(strcmp(ROOTCERT, ca_cert.c_str()) == 0)
    Serial.println("Certs are the same.");
  else
    Serial.println("Certs are different.")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around, I fixed it.

So `.c_str()` is just another way of pointing to the internal buffer of the `String` object.

Somehow that was messing things up. Using this code fixed it.

```cpp
char *dest;

dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ca_cert.length()+1));
strcpy(dest, ca_cert.c_str());

espClient.setCACert(dest);
```